# Is there any way to disable upfront indexing in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: eclipse, indexing, eclipse-cdt

When I'm using Eclipse CDT (the problem has existed for several versions now), the upfront indexing indexes a bunch of C header files, and pollutes the code completion with 100's of C functions which I will never ever use.

That prevents me from easily seeing what's actually in the namespace that I'm in at a glance, which is really annoying.

Why are they even included by default, and is there a way to remove them? Even an ugly workaround is fine, I just want a way to get rid of them that does not break my code.

Answer (score 6):

You can try tweaking the indexer settings. This can be done globally (in Window -> Preferences -> C++ -> Indexer) or in a per-project basis (in Project Properties -> C++ General -> Indexer). Try disabling `Index source files not included in the build` and `Index unused headers`.

Comment: Using your instructions I turned off the indexer. I frequently need to turn it on and off though, so I created a **Ctrl + Shift + I** shortcut to quickly open up the GUI Indexer settings so I can easily toggle the indexer on and off. Search for "Ctrl + Shift + I" in [my document here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LbuxOsDHfpMksGdpX5X-7l7o_TIIVFPkH2eD23cXUmA/edit?usp=sharing) for instructions. This is part of my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/eclipse) repo.